# Reassign variable in a List within for-loop

Tags: java

I want to reassign a variable within a for loop traversing over an ArrayList of Objects. But whatever I try it seems that nothing has any effect. Basically my code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    AbstractEnemy enemy = enemies.get(i);

    if (enemy.intersects(bullet)) {
        enemy.getsHit(bullet.getDamage());
        bulletList.remove(bullet);
        if (enemy.isDead()) {

            // This does not work
            enemy = new ExplodingEnemy(enemy.x, enemy.y);

        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use set method to set the values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a new enemy does not have any effect because you are assigning the enemy object to a temporary variable with the lifetime limited to a single loop iteration. If you want to store the enemy object in the list of enemies, you need to add a call of `set` method, like this:

```
enemy = new ExplodingEnemy(enemy.x, enemy.y);
enemies.set(i, enemy);
```

this would replace the old object representing an enemy with the one you have just created.

Answer (score 4):

```
enemy = new ExplodingEnemy(enemy.x, enemy.y);
```

is just changing the `reference` and not the `object` referenced by the reference. For that you need an internal handle to the object in form of an exposed method, which can modify the object from inside.

Answer (score 1):

This code : `enemy = new ExplodingEnemy(enemy.x, enemy.y);` just creates a new enemy object. The old enemy object remains as it is.